# Edit Metadata of PDF File with C#

Tags: c#, file, pdf, metadata

i searching for methods or libarys to edit metadata of a pdf file like the programm [becypdfmetaedit](http://www.becyhome.de/becypdfmetaedit/description_ger.htm).

I want to write a program and i need this opton in this program.
Perhaps you have some samples for c#.

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Using PDF Sharp works like this:

```
using System;
using PdfSharp.Pdf;
using PdfSharp.Pdf.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main (string[] args)
    {
      Program p = new Program();
      p.Test();

    }

    public void Test ()
    {
      PdfDocument document = PdfReader.Open ("Test.pdf");

      document.Info.Author = "ME";

      document.Save ("Result");
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: i have try it but producer can not changed :( its bad VS2008 says it is read only

Comment: Due to the reason that the software is open source you can modify it. So if you want to change the producer of the document you have to modify the PdfDocument.PrepareForSave() method. It uses the producer of the original document if the document is not created using PDFSharp. Change the Producer Property of PdfDocumentInformation to be settable and modify the PrepareForSave() method. This will do it.

Comment: Sadly pdfsharp doesn't support XMP metadata.

Comment: One other thing.  Most recent version of PdfSharp cannot handle iref streams.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36788746/pdfsharp-cannot-handle-this-pdf-feature-introduced-with-acrobat-6-error-while

Comment: Shortcut to download the DLL directly : https://www.dllme.com/dll/download/33562/PdfSharp.dll

Answer (score 8):

For PDFSharp:
If you would like to change/add the metadata on the **Custom Properties** of a PDF you can use the PdfDocument.Info.Elements object.

```
    String filename = @"d:\temp\Hugo-input.pdf";
    String outputfile = @"d:\temp\Hugo-output.pdf";
    PdfDocument document = PdfReader.Open(filename);
    document.Info.Elements.Add(new KeyValuePair<String,PdfItem>("/MyKey",new PdfString("MyValue")));
    document.Save(outputfile);
```

Always start a custom key with a slash!

You can find the key and value when you open this document in Adobe Acrobat Reader -> File -> Properties -> Custom.

This works with PDFSharp 1.32

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you can do it with [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Yes, with Info property you have access to the PDF Metadata and with the Metadata property you have access to the XML metadata (XMP format)

Answer (score 2):

Does the PdfDocumentInformation class from [PDF Sharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/) fulfill your requirements.

Comment: Can you explain me how it works @crauscher

Comment: http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/HelloWorld-sample.ashx shows hot to create a PdfDocument and how to change the PdfDocumentInformation (PdfDocument.Info). If you want to open an existing Pdf you can use toe PfdReader class froom PDF sharp

Comment: Can i remove/add xmp code to pdf ? 
Thanks for sample !

Answer (score 0):

[Aspose.PDF](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf-for-.net/default.aspx) or [Aspose.PDF.Kit](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.pdf.kit-for-.net/default.aspx) can do this for you.

Comment: Thank you for information but i search a not commercial solution

Comment: Aspose no longer allows to modify the producer name. Updating here to help anyone like me searching for solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Pimping here - [my company, Atalasoft, makes .NET components for working with images](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/).  Part of the suite includes the ability to read/write PDF document metadata.  It's not free, but it is run-time royalty free for desktop applications.

The code for reading is simple:

```
PdfDocumentMetadata metadata = PdfDocumentMetadata.FromStream(sourceStream);
```

to edit it and write it back to the same stream:

```
meta.Title = "Knicholas Knickleby";
meta.Author = "Edmund Wells";
sourceStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
meta.Append(sourceStream, false); // false means don't merge - overwrite
```

Custom fields are supported through a hashtable.