# Read all excel sheets and put them into arrays for further use

Tags: c#, arrays, excel

This is my first post in here and in general - I am quite new to the C#, so please forgive me any mistakes.
I am trying to do the below:

  1. I have an excel file with 3 excel sheets:
  **sheet1, sheet2, sheet3**
  .

  2. In each of those excel sheets I have a table with 3 columns:
  **ID, Name, NEW_ID**
  . All those 3 columns are
  **string**
  type so array would work as well.

  3. At the beginning of my code I want to access this excel file
  *just once*
  and output those sheets to the code as
  *3 separate arrays or lists and have them available to the end of the code execution*
  .

  4. I want to populate that data to arrays/lists because I have to search for given ID in those arrays later on (column ID) and return corresponding values from columns Name and NEW_ID. I will have to do it for around 100k IDs, therefore I don't want to go to the file each time as I believe, it will slow down entire process.

  5. I know how to access data from excel using OLEDB as I checked other topics in here, but I don't know how to output that data to 3 separate arrays/lists and search for given ID in those arrays/lists and return corresponding array items.

Thank you for any help!

This is the code I am running.
The problematic part is the **ReadExcel** class at the end of the code:

```
public class RecursiveFileProcessor
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string InputMainFolder = "C:\\US\\";
        string OutputMainFolder = "C:\\BAJ\\";
        foreach (string InputFile in GetFiles(InputMainFolder))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(InputFile);
            string InputPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(InputFile);
            string InputFileName = Path.GetFileName(InputFile);
            string OuputPath = InputPath.Replace(InputMainFolder, OutputMainFolder);
            string OutputFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(OuputPath, InputFileName);

            // To copy a folder's contents to a new location: 
            // Create a new target folder, if necessary. 
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(OuputPath))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(OuputPath);
                //Console.WriteLine("Ouput folder " + OuputPath + "created.");
            }

            // To copy a file to another location and  
            // overwrite the destination file if it already exists.
            if (File.Exists(OutputFile))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: File Already Exists: " + OutputFile);
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                System.IO.File.Copy(InputFile, OutputFile, true);
            }

            //Try to catch an exception
            try
            {
                //Here comes some important part of my code (that works fine)
            }

            catch (Exception exe)
            {
                //call LogFile method and pass argument as Exception message, event name, control name, error line number, current form name
                LogFile(exe.Message, exe.ToString(), exe.LineNumber(), InputFile, OutputMainFolder);
            }

        }
        //call excel reader for tests
        //THIS IS THE PLACE WHERE I WILL CALL MY EXCEL READER TO GET DATA INTO ARRAY/LIST/DATASET ETC
        {
            string MappingFile = "c:\\attributes mapping\\attributes mapping.xlsx";
            ReadExcel.ReadExcelToTable(MappingFile);
        }
        //That's the final line of the code
        Console.WriteLine("DONE: " + DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() + " UTC");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static IEnumerable<string> GetFiles(string path)
    {
        Queue<string> queue = new Queue<string>();
        queue.Enqueue(path);
        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            path = queue.Dequeue();
            try
            {
                foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
                {
                    queue.Enqueue(subDir);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            string[] files = null;
            try
            {
                files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            if (files != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                {
                    yield return files[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //This function writes exception details to the file in the output folder
    public static void LogFile(string sExceptionName, string sEventName, int nErrorLineNo, string sFileName, string sOutputFolder)
    {
        StreamWriter log;
        if (!File.Exists(sOutputFolder + "logfile.txt"))
        {
            log = new StreamWriter(sOutputFolder + "logfile.txt");
        }
        else
        {
            log = File.AppendText(sOutputFolder + "logfile.txt");
        }
        // Write to the file:
        log.WriteLine("File Name:" + sFileName);
        log.WriteLine("Data Time:" + DateTime.Now);
        log.WriteLine("Error Line No.:" + nErrorLineNo);
        log.WriteLine("Exception Name:" + sExceptionName);
        log.WriteLine("Event Name:" + sEventName);
        log.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------------------");

        // Close the stream:
        log.Close();
    }
}
//This part of code gets a line number where the exception appeared
public static class ExceptionHelper
{
    public static int LineNumber(this Exception e)
    {
        int linenum = 0;
        try
        {
            linenum = Convert.ToInt32(e.StackTrace.Substring(e.StackTrace.LastIndexOf(":line") + 5));
        }
        catch
        {
            //Stack trace is not available!
        }
        return linenum;
    }
}
```

Ok, I have managed to get that data into DataTables:

```
//Reads excel file and creates data sets from each excel sheet
public static DataSet ReadExcelToTable(string FileName)
{
    //string HDR = hasHeaders ? "Yes" : "No";
    string strConn;
    if (FileName.Substring(FileName.LastIndexOf('.')).ToLower() == ".xlsx")
        strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FileName + ";Extended Properties=\'Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';";
    else
       strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + FileName + ";Extended Properties=\'Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';";

    DataSet output = new DataSet();

    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn))
    {
        conn.Open();

        DataTable schemaTable = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(
            OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });

        foreach (DataRow schemaRow in schemaTable.Rows)
        {
            string sheet = schemaRow["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

            if (!sheet.EndsWith("_"))
            {
                try
                {
                    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet + "]", conn);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                    DataTable outputTable = new DataTable(sheet);
                    output.Tables.Add(outputTable);
                    new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(outputTable);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new Exception(ex.Message + string.Format("Sheet:{0}.File:F{1}", sheet, FileName), ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
```

Those DataTables (3) have to be available to the end of code execution.

ExcelReader will return 3 DataTables as output, right?
Then I have to continue with the code after the place where I have called ExcelReader class having those 3 DataTables as an Output.

And now I have to do something like that:

  1. Let's say that "InputPath" string is like that:

  C:\BAJ\Sheet1\ABCD
  **or**
  C:\BAJ\Sheet2\EFGH
  **or**
  C:\BAJ\Sheet3\IJKL (these are random names)

  2. If "InputPath" contains "Sheet1" --> open DataTable "Sheet1"

  3. Check if in DataTable "Sheet1" you can find ID=ABCD (taken as well from the “InputPath” variable) in ID column

  4. If found – return corresponding NAME and NEW_ID values as variables, let's say: sName and sNew_Id

Extra info: IDs in ID column are unique strings and can return only one Name and one New_Id (strings as well).

Any ideas?

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Comment: try using a hashtable/dictionary instead of an arraylist/list.

Comment: You can query the sheets directly into a datatable using your OLEDB provider and then you can use Linq to query that data later on in your program...

Comment: @John Bustos: Unfortunately, my mind is really blacked-out about using arrays and data sets. I am not very familiar with it in C# so a sample code would really help me to understand a lot. When I see it then it's easier to understand the process and ask more questions if I still don't understand some part of it. Big Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Guys, anyone? Pleeeese...

Comment: @user2835802 Your edit on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18128480/2000557) got rejected because you can't edit answers with comments like that. If you have a question, you should feel free to post a new question. Just try to be concise, include your attempt/research, and you will hopefully get an answer.