# PDFSharp losing annotations

Tags: c#, annotations, pdfsharp

Hello I am using the latest pre release version of PDFSharp and I am concatenating several documents. However, when I add the pages it is losing the annotation. Any idea why?

When I get the file like below, it has the annotation.

```
PdfDocument inputDocument1 = PdfReader.Open(fromDirectory, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import);
```

But, when I go to add it to the overall document, like below, it loses the annotation.

```
page = outputDocument.AddPage(page);
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: An MCVE would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that PDFSharp 1.50.4000-beta 3b has a bug, so I backed up to version 1.32.3057 and it started working.

Comment: Just noting that this issue still exists in the `Latest prerelease 1.50.4619-beta4c`.  But that going back to `Latest stable 1.32.3057` means you will run into problems like  https://stackoverflow.com/q/36788746/31326

Comment: @PeterM An MCVE would be appreciated.

Comment: @User241.007 The root problem is dependent on annotations being present in the  PDF being processed.  Unfortunately you can't create such an MCVE here as you cannot upload files.

Comment: @PeterM Post a link here or upload to the forum: http://forum.pdfsharp.net/

Comment: @User241.007 I pulled down the PDFSharp source from GitHub and found the issue.  I discovered 2 obvious bugs and have posted them on the PDFSharp bug forum.  Basically the code to clone annotations when doing `AddPage` has been commented out.

Answer (score -1):

To solve this issue, update this code:

```
page = outputDocument.AddPage(page);
```

To:

```
page = outputDocument.AddPage(page, AnnotationCopyingType.DeepCopy);
```

This fixed the issue for me.