# PDFsharp - C# - KeyValuePair - PowerShell conversion

Tags: c#, powershell, pdf, pdfsharp

Looking at the sample of C# code  ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18128480)). I'm trying to work out how to convert the required KeyPair syntax into PowerShell. I have an example of working PowerShell code, which will use the PDFsharp assembly to create a file, I'd like to modify that script to also modify a Custom Property of the PDF file.

Comment: Try `New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair[Type1,Type2]'`. Type1 should be `string`, Type2 is something like `PDFItem` or `PDFSharp.Item.PDFItem`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to create the `KeyValuePair` object manually, the `Info` property on `PdfDocument` has an `Add()` method that takes a string as the key and a `PdfItem` object as the value:

```bsh
$propertyKey = "/MyKey"
$propertyValue = "MyValue"
$document.Info.Add($propertyKey, [PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfString]::new($propertyValue))
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I got it using $document.Info.Elements.Add([KeyValuePair[string,PdfItem]]::new("/MyKey",[PdfString]::new("MyValue")))